# Execution order of touch command arguments

Tags: command-line, files, ls, touch

I have a list of files that are space separated and I want to use the `touch` command to update their timestamps in that order. But when I supply the filenames as arguments, the timestamps get updated in a different order.

```
touch 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt 10.txt 11.txt 12.txt
```

After running the command above and running `ls -t` (sorting by time modified) I get the following:

```
1.txt 10.txt 11.txt 12.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt
```

Does supplying arguments to commands not guarantee the execution order? If not, how can I update the timestamps of those files in that specific order?

Comment: If they all have the same timestamp, `ls` will show them in alphabetical order, which is what is happening.  You probably need to introduce an artificial delay, e. g. `for i in {1..12}; do touch ${i}.txt; sleep 1; done`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With no time specified, `touch` changes the timestamps of all its arguments to the current time at the time each file is touched, which should produce a different timestamp for each file, but in many cases this ends up applying the same timestamp to all its arguments; you can verify this by running `stat` on all the touched files. They are processed in the order specified on the command line.

To get the result you want, you need to loop and `touch` each file individually, with some delay:

```
for file in {1..12}.txt; do touch $file; sleep 0.1; done
```

(with more or less delay depending on the timestamp resolution of the underlying file system).

Note that `ls -t` lists files sorted by descending timestamp; to see increasing times you need to use `ls -rt`.

Comment: It looks like even using a loop, it executes quickly enough to all have the same timestamp. Do you know of another alternative?

Comment: @spencer.sm see my update.

Comment: @spencer.sm You could add a little delay between two touch (via sleep)

Comment: It looks like on my system it can only be sorted to the nearest second. That's why it wasn't showing the correct order using `ls`. Even `stat` only went to the second. But after giving it a delay of 1 second it worked for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little cumbersome, but if it's in a script, I would use a for loop.

ex:

```
for x in 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt [as many as you want here]; do touch $x; done
```

This would result in them always being created in the order given. You of course can change the names to be whatever and not follow any sort of pattern. If you are creating files with the same name or a numeric pattern like in your example, I would do this:

```
for x in $(seq 1 10); do touch $x.txt; done
```

Comment: That actually doesn't work. Try using `ls -t` after and you'll see that it goes in the same order I do not want... `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3...`

Comment: @spencer.sm, provide the output of `ls -l --full-time`.  I do not observe that `ls`'s time sorting respects sub-second precision.  However, using `--full-time` or getting the time via `stat` shows the files were indeed touched in the desired order.

Comment: @spencer.sm It worked fine for me. `ls -t` as well as `ls -l --full-time` both showed them in the exact order `12.txt, 11.txt, 10.txt, 9.txt...`. Your output seems to be showing numerical sorting.

Comment: Same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3814290/3498950

Comment: Well it probably depends on your system then. Stephen Kitt is absolutely right then, you need to add delay to the loop.